# How to remove default margins from microcharts (xamarin)?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to remove the default margins in microcharts and stretch the graphic to the end of the frame using xamarin.

My xaml code is:

```
              <Frame 
                   BorderColor="White"
                   Margin="10,0,10,0"
                   CornerRadius="10"
                   HasShadow="True"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                <StackLayout>
                    <forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1"  
                     HeightRequest="150"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>

             </Frame>
```

My c# code is:

```
 List<EntryMicrocharts> entries = new List<EntryMicrocharts>
    {
        new EntryMicrocharts ((float)TemperaturesList[0].AvgTemperature)
        {
            Color=SKColor.Parse("#ffffff"),
            Label = Info1Forecast,
            ValueLabel = Math.Round((float)TemperaturesList[0].AvgTemperature,0).ToString() + "°C",
            ValueLabelColor = SKColor.Parse("#ffffff")
        },....... more same code here
        };
                Chart1.Chart = new LineChart()
                {
                    Entries = entries,
                    PointSize = 30,
                    LineSize = 12,
                    LabelTextSize = 35f,
                    LabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    ValueLabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent,
                    LabelColor = SKColor.Parse("#ffffff"),
                };
            }

        }
```

[image: chart]

How to stretch the graphic to the end of the frame ?

I try with `Margin = "0,0,0,0"` in xaml code but this not work for me.

Is there a way to remove margins ?

Comment: Try setting Padding = 0 to your Frame

Comment: Тhis option stretches the graphic verticaly but there is still a lot of distance between the graphic and the frame on the horizontal part

Comment: When I remove the frame completely from the code, there is again a distance between the graphic and the display itself on the horizontal part

Comment: Can you update your complete Xaml, what is the parent layout where Frame is placed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet-ad/Microcharts/issues/125) with width of LineChart. You can either fix this bug in MicroCharts or try changing to another type of charts if that works for you, like BarChart:

```
                Chart1.Chart = new BarChart()
                {   
                    Entries = entries,
                    LabelTextSize = 35f,
                    LabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    ValueLabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent,
                    LabelColor = SKColor.Parse("#FFFFFF")
                };
```

Also, add appropriate padding in XAML, like `Padding = "2"`.

[image]